# Lista simple de vectores

Tags: java

estoy tratando de crear una lista simplemente enlazada en la que cada nodo es un vector de tipo `Image`,
este es el metodo que estoy utilizando para agregar el nuevo nodo pero la tercera linea como la penultima me tiran el siguiente error:

> "cannot infer type arguments for Node<>"

```
public void Add(E[] Element) {
    if (this.first == null) {
        this.first = new Node<>(Element);
    } else {
        Node<E> aux = first;
        while (aux.hasNext()) {
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
        aux.setNext(new Node<>(Element));
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor comparte el código de la definición de tu clase.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas especificar el tipo de Nodo. En tu ejemplo, el tipo de Nodo es E. Tu método queda asi:

```
public void Add(E[] Element) {
    if (this.first == null) {
        this.first = new Node<E>(Element);
    } else {
        Node<E> aux = first;
        while (aux.hasNext()) {
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
        aux.setNext(new Node<E>(Element));
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta javier!!!